# bash - All possible combinations of words from different files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have *n* files with one word per line

```
file 1    file 2   file 3 ...
1_a       2_a       3_a
1_b       2_b       3_b
1_c                 3_c
```

I want to write a bash script that takes all this files and generates all the possible combination of n words (one from each file).

In my example I want this result :

```
1_a 2_a 3_a
1_a 2_a 3_b
1_a 2_a 3_c
1_a 2_b 3_a
1_a 2_b 3_b
1_a 2_b 3_c
1_b 2_a 3_a
1_b 2_a 3_b
1_b 2_a 3_c
1_b 2_b 3_a
1_b 2_b 3_b
1_b 2_b 3_c
1_c 2_a 3_a
1_c 2_a 3_b
1_c 2_a 3_c
1_c 2_b 3_a
1_c 2_b 3_b
1_c 2_b 3_c
```

I have tried to do to this with paste and awk but I have failed. How can I do this ?

Comment: Did you consider writing a small script with 3 concentric loops ? Or are you looking for a one-liner ?

Comment: @MelBurslan the number of files is not fixed : between 2 and 10. But I am not looking for a one-liner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a recursive function that calls itself while there're files to process:

```
#!/bin/bash

process () {
    local prefix=$1
    local file=$2
    shift 2
    while read line ; do
        if (($#)) ; then                  # There are still unprocessed files.
            process "$prefix $line" "$@"
        else                              # Reading the last file.
            printf '%s\n' "$prefix $line"
        fi
    done < "$file"
}

process '' "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
parallel --line-buffer --keep-order echo :::: file1 :::: file2 :::: file3
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#multiple-input-sources

Answer (score 1):

I know you said `bash` but this is perfectly suited to a language such as `python 3.3+`

```
import sys
from contextlib import ExitStack
from itertools import product

with ExitStack() as stack:
  files = [stack.enter_context(open(f)) for f in sys.argv[1:]]
  for x in product(*files):
    x = [y.rstrip('\n') for y in x]
    print(*x)
```

Put the code above in a file called `combo.py` and call it thus `python combo.py file_1 file_2 file_3`
It generates

```
1_a 2_a 3_a
1_a 2_a 3_b
1_a 2_a 3_c
1_a 2_b 3_a
1_a 2_b 3_b
1_a 2_b 3_c
1_b 2_a 3_a
1_b 2_a 3_b
1_b 2_a 3_c
1_b 2_b 3_a
1_b 2_b 3_b
1_b 2_b 3_c
1_c 2_a 3_a
1_c 2_a 3_b
1_c 2_a 3_c
1_c 2_b 3_a
1_c 2_b 3_b
1_c 2_b 3_c
```

Answer (score 1):

Expansion of curly brackets in bash provides just the right tool for this job.
Consider a simple case like:

```
$ echo {1..3}{a..c}
1a 1b 1c 2a 2b 2c 3a 3b 3c
```

In your example you would have something like this:

```
$ echo {1_a,1_b,1_c}{2_a,2_b}{3_a,3_b,3_c}
1_a2_a3_a 1_a2_a3_b 1_a2_a3_c 1_a2_b3_a 1_a2_b3_b 1_a2_b3_c 1_b2_a3_a 1_b2_a3_b 1_b2_a3_c 1_b2_b3_a 1_b2_b3_b 1_b2_b3_c 1_c2_a3_a 1_c2_a3_b 1_c2_a3_c 1_c2_b3_a 1_c2_b3_b 1_c2_b3_c
```

which is correct but hard to read. For better presentation you could put the generated output into an array and then print the array:

```
$ combos=({1_a,1_b,1_c}{2_a,2_b}{3_a,3_b,3_c})
$ for i in "${combos[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
1_a2_a3_a
1_a2_a3_b
1_a2_a3_c
1_a2_b3_a
1_a2_b3_b
1_a2_b3_c
1_b2_a3_a
1_b2_a3_b
1_b2_a3_c
1_b2_b3_a
1_b2_b3_b
1_b2_b3_c
1_c2_a3_a
1_c2_a3_b
1_c2_a3_c
1_c2_b3_a
1_c2_b3_b
1_c2_b3_c
```

There are many ways of adding a gap between each combo element to make them look like:

```
1_a 2_a 3_a
..
..
```

but that is a different question which you can ask separately.